# background color not showing in Internet Explorer and Opera

Tags: internet-explorer, css, menu

This menu works great, except my background disappears in Opera and Internet Explorer plus any tips on better Explorer compatibility would be awesome.

It's also using `foundation.css` from the foundation framework if your familiar with that one.

If you want to see it in action: http://www.pink-realty.com

```
    .elephant-menu {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 40px;
        z-index: 50 !important;
        opacity: 1;
        background: url(../images/misc/button-gloss.png) repeat-x 0 -34px, -moz-linear-    gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 0%, transparent 100%) #e51d9b;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.28);
        background: url(../images/misc/button-gloss.png) repeat-x 0 -34px, -webkit-    gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255,255,255,.4)), to(transparent)) #e51d9b;
        border: 1px solid rgba(229, 33, 155, 1);
        -webkit-transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        font: 16px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
       }

    .elephant-menu li { 
    list-style-type: none !important;
    text-transform: capitalize !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    float: left !important;
    position: relative !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 11px 5px 10px;
    display: block;
   }

   .elephant-menu li:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #9c126f;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px black;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px black;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   }

   .elephant-menu a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
   }
```

Comment: Specifically, what "background" are you talking about?  Your site appears to only have a white background.  Please post all relevant code in your question.  Links should only be used to demonstrate problem, not eliminate the need to post the code.

Comment: Again, please post the relevant HTML code in your question.  Otherwise, when your link goes dead or gets fixed, this question will be useless to future readers.

Comment: What version of IE are you testing? You don't appear to have a fall back background-color for IE8 and Opera, that don't support the gradient rules you've specified.

Comment: Both good answers! I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with adding something like this.. modify your colors and alpha.

```
.elephant-menu {
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0px, #E5219B 70%);
}
```